# error in disabling network connection in Python

Tags: python, wifi

I have tried the below code but got

error: Cannot complete this function.

```
import os 
def enable():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Wifi' enabled")

def disable():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Wifi' disabled")
```

and tried 'Wi-Fi' and 'Wi-Fi2' instead of 'Wifi'
but got the same error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it just leaves 'Cannot complete this function'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need administrator rights to execute this function. Rightclick your python file, run as admin, and see if it works.
If you use pycharm or visual studio code, try running it as admin and execute it from there. If it still doesnt work, try replacing 'Wi-fi' with "Wi-fi"